# Alter table to change datatype causing very large database file

Tags: sql-server, database, data-conversion

I am working on a database that is about 6Gb.  I need to convert all the non unicode columns to unicode e.g. change all varchar to nvarchar.

I had scripted this using ALTER statements like `ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn nvarchar(...)` but I found the database size increased massively afterwards. The .mdf file grew to over 70Gb which surprised me.  I know that unicode takes x2 times the space of varchar but even if the database was all varchar and was converted I would expect it's maximum size to be 12Gb.

I tried to shrink the database and files to see if it was unallocated space but this had little effect and `sp_spaceused` indicated there was not an excessive amount of unallocated space.

Does anyone know why the database would have grown so large?  I'm very keen to understand what would have caused this.

I have managed to change the column datatypes to unicode by creating a new database scripted from the old database and importing all the data and the result was an increase in size of only 1Gb, so I'd like to understand why altering the column datatypes caused such growth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked if the increased size it's on the log file? If this is the problem, truncate it by making backups of your db. This is the most probable problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply JotaBe, unfortunately no, it's the .mdf file and not the .ldf file that is growing large.

Comment: Check if the tables have clustered indexes with low fill factor. Try making DBCC DBREINDEX in some of the bigger ones and see the result. If your nvarchar are very big, and you have a low fill factor you can have a lot of spare space reserved for the tables. This only applies to the clusterd indexes.

Comment: You were right JotaBe... it was the log file!  I made a mistake with the restore for the database and put the log file in the directory where the data file should have been and the data file in the logs directory.  So that explains it, I was confusing the 2 files.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

well, such increase would yes create a big overhead. SQL may be internally doing a copy of the column to increase it. But 70gb is indeed too big

Also, are you talking about 70 gb of allocated or actual data size?
because there is a difference. Check the auto growth property on your database files, if it is set to several GB or a very big percentage, that would explain

Comment: Thanks for that Diego.  I checked that but the auto growth was 10MB but I made a mistake with the data and log files and it was that confusion that lead me to believe that it was the data file that was growing and not the log file.